# Select of distinct (col1,col2) where col1 is string and col2 is int

Tags: mysql

How to obtain a distinct combination of col1 and col2 where former is integer and later is string in mysql

Comment: `select distinct col1, col2 from your_table` ???

Answer (score 0):

Use `GROUP BY`

```
SELECT col1,col2 FROM TABLE
GROUP BY col1,col2
```

Answer (score 0):

**Using `distinct`**

```
select distinct
  col1,col2 
from
  tbl
;
```

or

**Using `group by`**

```
select 
  col1,col2 
from
  tbl
group by col1, col2
;
```